# BizTalk Tracking for an Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Step:

1. Click Start, click All Programs, click Microsoft BizTalk Server 20xx, and then click BizTalk Server Administration.
2. In the console tree, expand BizTalk Server Administration, expand the BizTalk group, expand Applications, and then expand the application containing the orchestration for which you want to configure tracking.
3. Click Orchestrations, right-click the orchestration for which you want to configure tracking, and then click Properties.
4. Click the Tracking tab, select the tracking options you want, as described in the following table, and then click OK.

Track Events - Orchestration start and end --check box enable
Track Events - Message send and receive --check box enable
Track Events - Shape start and end --check box enable

Question:

I ran query completed instances through BizTalk admin console I haven't seen anything same time other few application I'm able to see completed orchestration. So, what make different to not track completed instances for such application ?

Is this issue related to SQL agent job for BizTalk?
Any specific details about how to run query using SQL management studio to find out tracking information for such application that being not track through BizTalk admin console?

Comment: Are the Agent jobs running?

Comment: Which SQL agent job are you referring @john ?

Comment: These Jobs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919776/description-of-the-sql-server-agent-jobs-in-biztalk-server

Comment: Thanks for link @Johns-305 ...all sql agent jobs running except monitor BizTalk server is failed on step 2 but I didn't think it's causing issue to Track completed orchestrations for all my application from biztalk admin console.

Comment: Did the Orchestrations execute after you enabled tracking on them?  Do you have a separate tracking host?   Do the Orchestrations that are tracked run on the same host that aren't get tracked?

Comment: 1.yes the orchestration was executed after tacking was enabled  and I only have issue on prod, other lower environment for same application I have seen tracking information

Comment: 2. I have seen we use BiztalkServerTrackingHost and tracking properties enable for that host.

Comment: 3. Nope, I can tacked services instances as host name what we are using for all 4 orchestration but when I was trying to tack through service name (orchestration name) I'm not getting anything---so ultimately something is not running properly ---thanks for asking in details @Dijkgraaf

Comment: Is there any dependency for tracking on default pipeline what we are using for receive location and send port b'coz I've just show all 4 defaults pipelines tacking not enable ...just it's thought @Dijkgraaf